# tbody tag element returns empty when generating basic table using D3

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I am trying to generate a table using D3 reading from a external json file,also passing a parameter "fieldNamesUnique" to the function. The function executes with no errors however the tbody tag is empty.

Here is the JSON data:

```
[
  {
   "Label": "External-Partner-Induced",
   "Count": 9
  },
  {
   "Label": "Null",
   "Count": 1
  },
  {
   "Label": "FCTS-Induced",
   "Count": 66
  },
  {
   "Label": "EI-Partner-Induced",
   "Count": 78
  }
 ]
```

Here is the d3 code

```
        function testFunction(fieldNamesUnique) {
            data = d3.json('json/dataQualityIssuesCategory.json')
            tabulate(data, ['Category', 'Count']);  

            }
          function tabulate(data, columns) {
                var table = d3.select('#response').append('table')
                var thead = table.append('thead')
                var tbody = table.append('tbody');

                // append the header row
                thead.append('tr')
                  .selectAll('th')
                  .data(columns)
                  .enter()
                  .append('th')
                    .text(function (column) { return column; });

                // create a row for each object in the data
                var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('tr');

          // create a cell in each row for each column
            var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
                .data(function (row) {
                    return columns.map(function (column) {
                      return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                    });
                  })
                .enter()
                .append('td')
                .text(function (d) { return d.value; });
          return table;
        }
```

And here is the results:
[page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq35U.png)

Could someone help me find out why the tbody tag is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json` doesn't return anything (technically speaking, it returns an object related to the *request*).

Therefore, you cannot do:

```
data = d3.json('json/dataQualityIssuesCategory.json')
```

Instead of that, `data` has to be the parameter inside the callback:

```
d3.json("dataQualityIssuesCategory.json", function(data){
    //parameter here -------------------------------^
    //code using 'data' here
});
```

Here is a plunker with your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/jJQHWSz0wvQkWFqULq7t?p=preview

**PS**: I'm answering **only** your question (*"why the tbody tag is empty?"*). Your code, as you can see by the result, has some problems, which are not in the scope of this question.